# Factorization of a list with composite integers to a combined list of all prime factors

Tags: list-manipulation

The following function io[aIn_] produces a list bOut containing ALL the prime factors of an Integer via the standard function FactorInteger[].
My code is:

```
io[aIn_] := 
(bOut = {};fi = FactorInteger[aIn];Do[bOut~AppendTo~(PadLeft[{}, fi[[i, 2]], fi[[i, 1]]] ), {i, 1, Length[fi]}]; bOut = bOut // Flatten )
```

I would like to know whether there are other solutions for this "problem"?

My solution does not work with e.g. aIn={12321}; io[aIn] nor with io[{12321}] or io[{12, 21}] and I do not understand all the warnings given by MMA.

I do not like to build a function that treats the integers of an input seperately and combines the results into a single list.
I prefer a solution for io[] with "list in of composite integers" gives " list out of all prime factors".

Comment: Surprised no one has picked this up yet. Lots of ways, here's one: `SetAttributes[f, Listable]; f[n_] := 
 Sequence @@ ConstantArray[#1, #2] & @@@ FactorInteger[n]`

Comment: I'm not sure from your last sentence whether you want all the factors of a list of composite numbers to be in a single list, or whether each number's factors should appear in its own list. My solution does the latter, but you can `Apply` `Join` to my solution to get the former. Or you could just multiply the input numbers together first..

Comment: @Aky: Thank you, I learned from your first comment how to make my function io Listable with SetAttributes. My solution does work now.

Comment: @Aky: Will you please make from your second comment an answer. The use of Sequence was new for me.

Comment: You're welcome. You've probably realised that rasher's solution, while being the same approach as mine, is cleaner - the pure function `ConstantArray[#1,# 2]&` I used  was redundant.

Comment: Making a function `Listable` is good when the function operates on an individual element (like an integer), and you want to be able to apply it to each element of an arbitrarily nested list. Obviously that may or may not be desirable. As it turns out, `FactorInteger` is already `Listable`. So we should now (if needed) clear the `Listable` attribute by doing `ClearAttributes[f, Listable]` from my function and change it to `f[n_] := Sort@Flatten@Apply[ConstantArray, FactorInteger[n], {-2}]` so it now works on numbers and (nested) lists to return a single sorted list with all the factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Produces same results as your example:

```
io[n_] := Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[n]
```

No real advantage other than cleaner and lower memory use, since yours is fast already.

To get list of all factors of a list of integers:

```
io[n_] := Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ Join @@ FactorInteger /@ n
```

No need to set any attributes doing it this way. Prepend `Sort` if you want all factors from all numbers in submitted list grouped, e.g.:

```
io[n_] := Sort@(Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ Join @@ FactorInteger /@ n)
```

Answer (score 2):

The prime factors of an input integer`n`are returned by`FactorInteger`in the first positions of a list of pairs. The second position in each pair is the exponent of the corresponding prime, which you want to discard.

```
PrimeFactors[n_Integer]:=FactorInteger[n][[All, 1]]
```

For an input list of integers`n`, find the prime factors from each integer in the input list, and then find the`Union`of the result. Note that`FactorInteger`accepts lists of integers as well as single integers.

```
PrimeFactors[n_List]:=Union[Flatten[FactorInteger[n][[All, All, 1]]]]
```

This is my interpretation of the last sentence of your post. However, the second last sentence appears to contradict my assumption. Perhaps you want the prime factors of each integer in the input list`n`to be in a separate list. Then you could use

```
PrimeFactors[n_List] := FactorInteger[n][[All, All, 1]]
```

Comment: I think he wants the various prime factors in their respective multiplicities, rather than just the unique ones.

Comment: @KennyColnago: As Aky wrote, I want in the outputlist All factors, in the inputlist the composite integers